# How can I run a NodeJS script whenever a webpage loads?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, web, hosting

Let me explain my project to the best of my ability. I am working with webpack and deck.gl to make a JavaScript app/website that displays map data. The map data is from a JSON file, but that JSON data only gets appended if I run a NodeJS web scraper program that I wrote.

Two things, how can I automate this script so it runs whenever the website (index.html) is loaded for the first time, and how would I go about hosting a website like this on a platform outside of my localhost?

Thanks in advance.

---

**Fix / Solution:**

> How would can I automate this script so it runs whenever the website (index.html) is loaded for the first time

I ended up creating a web server via [Express](https://expressjs.com/) and called my code as a function (scrape.js file shown below)

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const scrape = require('./scrape.js');

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    scrape();
})

app.listen(3000);
```

> and how would I go about hosting a website like this on a platform outside of my localhost

Almost every major hosting platform allows you to host Node applications so I decided to use [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/) - specifically [AWS EC2 Instance](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how can I automate this script so it runs whenever the website (index.html) is loaded for the first time

1. Create a web server (e.g. using Express.js)
2. Rewrite the script so it can be called as a function, then call it when the route for your homepage is accessed

e.g.

```
const yourscript = require("./yourscript.js");

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    yourscript();
    res.render('index')
})
```

(Not an exhaustive example, do read the Express.js documentation)

And make sure you load the webpage by requesting it from the webserver (e.g. `http://localhost:3000/` and not accessing the file from the filesystem directly).

> how would I go about hosting a website like this on a platform outside of my localhost?

Find a hosting service designed for running a Node.js application and follow their instructions.

Comment: Thank you. When you say "rewrite the script so it can be called as a function," does this just involve wrapping the code in a function? When I try this it comes up with a TypeError saying "x is not a function"

Comment: @devon66h — Since I've absolutely no idea what the script does, I can't say.